# How to convert array of objects to Spring application.properties

Tags: java, json

I'm using Jackson to convert objects include Array object to application.properties file but the result when convert array object look not good as I expected.
This is my code:

```
 JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer().rootName("application").prettyPrint(false);
 String json = serializer.serialize(configDto.getValue());

 ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
 JsonNode tree = om.readTree(json);
 Properties props;
 JavaPropsMapper mapper = new JavaPropsMapper();

 props = mapper.writeValueAsProperties(tree);
 props.store(new FileOutputStream(file), "");
```

> Input:

```
{
  "nation": [
      {
        "key": "France"
      },
      {
        "key": "Spain"
      },
      {
        "key": "England"
      }
    ],
    "movie": "Avatar 2"
}
```

> Result:

```
application.nation.1 = France
application.nation.2 = Spain
application.nation.3 = England
application.movie = Avatar 2
```

> Result expect:

```
application.nation[1] = France
application.nation[2] = Spain
application.nation[3] = England
application.movie = Avatar 2
```

How I can convert data like result I expect? Sorry for my bad English! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly make your `nation` in your json an array. I'm sorry, I haven't tested it.

```
{
  "nation": ["France", "Spain", "England"],
  "movie": "Avatar 2"
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it the same result!